# Solr gets results only when search term is capitalized

Tags: solr, token

I have the following problem with Solr search.

When I search for words which begin with `"oe", "ae" or "ue" (Which is in German the same like ö, ä and ü) and the search term is not capitalized`, then Solr returns 0 results.

But, when I search for the same word `with capitalized first char of the word, I get results` from Solr.

When I execute the search in a debug mode I see that `the non-capitalized search term is always converted from eg. "ue" -> "u"`

```
"response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []
  },
  "debug": {
    "rawquerystring": "uetze",
    "querystring": "uetze",
    "parsedquery": "(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((content:utze | title:utze | keywords:utze | description:utze^2.0 | browserTitle:utze^3.0)))/no_coord",
    "parsedquery_toString": "+(content:utze | title:utze | keywords:utze | description:utze^2.0 | browserTitle:utze^3.0),
    "explain": {},
    "QParser": "ExtendedDismaxQParser",
    "altquerystring": null,
```

While indexing following filters are used:

```
<fieldType name="text"        class="solr.TextField"      sortMissingLast="true"  positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer            class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter               class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords-de.txt" /> <!-- DE -->
        <filter               class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter               class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory" /> <!-- DE -->
        <filter               class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" /> <!--  DE -->
        <filter               class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter               class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1" />
    </analyzer>

</fieldType>
```

Does anyone know how to avoid this convertion?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's expected behaviour according to your configuration, since `GermanNormalizationFilterFactory` do the following:

```
'ß' is replaced by 'ss'
'ä', 'ö', 'ü' are replaced by 'a', 'o', 'u', respectively.
'ae' and 'oe' are replaced by 'a', and 'o', respectively.
'ue' is replaced by 'u', when not following a vowel or q.
```

So, you could remove it, and the `ue` will not be replaced to `u`. Another possible approach that could help (I'm not sure, I fully get your use-case), is to place `<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />` above `GermanNormalizationFilterFactory`